# BRIDGE command in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, bridge

Occasionally I need to write queries accessing tables in both an MS Access database and an Oracle database. This can be done in MS Access, but Access limits the SQL I can use and has weird syntax.

The BRIDGE command in SQL Developer sounds perfect for this, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. When trying to execute this:

```
BRIDGE FallEnrollment2012 AS CentralServer(SELECT * FROM "Fall 2012 Enrollment 10-24-12")
SELECT * FROM FallEnrollment2012 WHERE ROWNUM <=10
```

I get this error message:

```
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
00900. 00000 -  "invalid SQL statement"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Between BRIDGE and FallEnrollment2012 a syntax error is indicated, but I can't figure out what the issue is. As far as I can tell from the examples I've looked at, it's correct as written. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How are you running this statement?  `bridge` only works in SQL Developer worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in SQL Developer 4.0 Beta1 & Beta2.

The workaround is to start SQL Developer , Tools > Migration > Scratch Editor  .Then open the worksheet and run your BRIDGE command. 
In this way the migration plugin is loaded which provides the BRIDGE functionality.

A fix is being worked on

Regards,

Dermot.

Comment: thanks Dermot<br>
you might also like to know<br>
that the BRIDGE command doesn't recognise<br>
the datatype "ReplicationId"<br>
in MSAccess<br>
so none of the PK columns migrated successfully